# Notepad++ code folding issue

Tags: notepad++

I have been using notepad++ for a while and generally its great.  I am having an issue with the code folding feature.  It works fine for the most part, but when there are multiple nested BEGIN/END blocks, the folding doesn't work properly. The example below is taken from a script I am working on.  I pulled out the code since it doesn't really matter, or at least I don't think it does.  I am seeing this in .sql files.

```
BEGIN 
    BEGIN----1
        BEGIN ----2
        END----2
        BEGIN----3
        END----3
    END----1
END
```

The fold at the top level starts with the "BEGIN" and should stop at "END", but notepad++ seems to recognize the "END----3" as the end of the code block and stops folding down at that point.  Any tips/advice to get notepad++ to properly match the nested begin/end statements.

Comment: the code may not matter, but the language probably does. What language do you have Notepad++ set to for this document?

Comment: I chose a language that has BEGIN/END and your example worked fine. Which language are you using?

Comment: I am seeing this in .sql files

Comment: It works OK in `.sql` files for me. Are you running the latest version? Have you changed any related settings in Preferences?

Comment: If you have any `CASE` statements, the code folding breaks unless you put the `WHEN` on its own line. See https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15073/folding-behavior-of-sql-code